How add a request rule to Backpack-Laravel?
I need to dynamically assemble request rules depending on the value of a model field.
I have a model author with a field string $rule. This field can store string values ​​for the request - integer, string, boolean etc.
Create crud model
protected function setupCreateOperation()
{
     $this->crud->setValidation(AutorCreateRequest::class);
     $this->crud->addFields(...);
}

Getting the value of the type field in the current model inside AuthorCreateRequest failed - this is normal. This class knows nothing about the current model.
So I need to add dynamic rules to the current ones somewhere inside the setupCreateOperation method. How do I do this?
For example
protected function setupCreateOperation()
{
    // AutorCreateRequest with default rule
    $this->crud->setValidation(AutorCreateRequest::class);
    $this->crud->addFields(...);

    // I would like to see something like this
    // add new rules to default rules 
    $this->crud->request->rule->add([
        'value' => [
              'required',
              $type
        ]
    ]);
}


You can dynamically customize the rules array within your request class AutorCreateRequest:class
I do it within the rules() function. In my case, I customize the array on the basis of some setting or request().

Thanks for the answer. I need to collect rules depending on the value of the current model field. The request does not have the current model data, so it seems to me that dynamic rules need to be moved to the CRUD.

You were right. I checked again the possibility to use the field value from the current model. The request that is loaded when viewed really cannot work with the data, but it is also loaded when saving. Therefore, I can get the data from the request(). Thank you very much for your answer.
